# Pass props from the root component to AppNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-apollo

I have an AppNavigator inside of an App root component. I need to change the initialRouteName in AppNavigator depends on the props of the root component. In a root component when user is signIn i save a credentials in Keychain. And i need to do this way:
userLoggedIn ? HomeScreen : AuthScreen
Can you tell me please how can i sent userLoggedIn props from the root App component to the AppNavigator?

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'
import { ApolloProvider as ApolloHooksProvider } from 'react-apollo-hooks'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain'
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator'

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000'
})

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const tokens = await Keychain.getGenericPassword()
  const accessToken = tokens.accessToken
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: accessToken ? `Bearer ${accessToken}` : ''
    }
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true
})

const App = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  useEffect(async () => {
    const tokens = await Keychain.getGenericPassword()
    const accessToken = tokens.accessToken
    if (accessToken) {
      setLoggedIn(true)
    }
  })
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <ApolloHooksProvider client={client}>
        <AppNavigator userLoggedIn={loggedIn} />
      </ApolloHooksProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

AppNavigator.js:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { HomeScreen, AuthScreen } from './screens'

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    AUTH_SCREEN: AuthScreen,
    HOME: HomeScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AUTH_SCREEN',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the switch navigator.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#docsNav.